# predict_prob OpenCV 3.0.0 Rtrees - Random forest classifier

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to get probability estimates for my RTree classifier. In OpenCV 2.4 a function predict_prob exists for the RTree class, this one is gone in the 3.0.0 branch.

As an alternative I've tried to get the amount of votes per class (using flags in the predict function), but that seems to crash OpenCV. For now I'll switch to version 2.4.11, but I'm curious if anyone figured this out.

Relevant documentation:
2.4.11: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html
3.0.0: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html

Relevant code in 3.0.0:

```
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::RTrees> forest = cv::ml::RTrees::load<cv::ml::RTrees>(_ModelFileFld->getStringValue());
    cv::Mat result;
    forest->predict(instance, result, cv::ml::RTrees::Flags::PREDICT_SUM);
```